# How to apply a higher weight to a feature in BQML?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to train an xgboost classification model using BQML. But I'd like to give one feature a higher weight. I couldn't find any documentation about assigning feature weights. There is CLASS_WEIGHTS to assign weights to class labels but that is not what I want. BQML [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create).

I feel like this feature is not available yet and I have to create handmade models using sklearn.

Comment: I did not see any documentation for this fucntion at the moment. Thes closes I can share is this syntax for ML Weight function: " https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-weights#mlweights_syntax "

Comment: Thank you. And I agree. This function doesn't exist ATM. Also, it appears that the link you shared is primarily about standardizing features, i.e. putting all continuous numerical features on the same scale of mean = 0, standard deviation = 1. As you said, not the thing we are looking for.